# why and when to override and use OnPreRender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m working on a code written by a another developer as below

```
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid();

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

I would have called  `PopulateGrid();` method in the Page_Load event after checking the `postback` property. Are there any benefits we are getting in calling this method inside this `overriden OnPreRender`. And is it necessary to call `base.OnPreRender(e)`:?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are there any benefits we are getting in calling this method inside this overridden `OnPreRender`?

The PreRender phase occurs after the postback event is raised (e.g., `button_Click`), so by calling `PopulateGrid` in `OnPreRender`, it can take into account the button that was clicked. This is useful if the button modifies the data source.

> And is it necessary to call `base.OnPreRender(e)`?

Strictly speaking, if you're deriving from `Control`, `WebControl`, `UserControl`, or `Page`, then calling `base.OnPreRender` merely raises the `PreRender` event, so it's not *necessary* to call it unless someone has hooked up a handler for that event. If you're deriving from something else, then you need to check whether the base class does something extra in `OnPreRender`.

But I recommend you always call the base method, in case some other component needs to handle the `PreRender` event in the future.

Comment: `Calling base.OnPreRender merely raises the PreRender event` Not necessarily. I wouldn't advise not bothering to ccall the `base` method.

Comment: @MichaelLiu can you pls clarify "This is useful if the button modifies the data source." or give me an example of this pls

Comment: @Dev: Suppose your page has a `deleteButton` that deletes a row from your database table, and `PopulateGrid` retrieves data from the table and binds it to the grid. By calling `PopulateGrid` in `OnPreRender`, the grid will reflect the deletion made by the button, since `OnPreRender` is called after `deleteButton_Click`. Calling `PopulateGrid` in `Page_Load` or `OnLoad` would be too early since that happens *before* `deleteButton_Click`.