# "Failed to load view state" Error When dynamically loading user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, viewstate

I am having a User control [ascx] which is a radgrid. It also has a Edit column template which allow user to Insert/ change/update the values.

I am loading this user control on click of a button [Say EDIT] in aspx page.

When I click on `EDIT` button of aspx page the user control loads perfectly, but when I click on the `Add New Record` of user control I get this error message.

> Failed to load viewstate. The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save
>   viewstate during the previous request. For example, when adding
>   controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match
>   the type and position of the controls added during the initial
>   request.

//code of user control -ascx

```
<telerik:RadGrid AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
    AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False"
    Height="410px" ID="rgrd1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnUpdateCommand="rgrd1_UpdateCommand"
    OnInsertCommand="rgrd1_InsertCommand"  OnNeedDataSource="rgrd1_NeedDataSource" GridLines="None">

    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="top" CommandItemStyle-Wrap="False" CommandItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
        DataKeyNames="Type">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditColumn" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"
                HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="ImageButton">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"
                HeaderText="Type" UniqueName="Type">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="TypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
            </EditColumn>
            <FormTemplate>
                <table>
                        <td>
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtType" Width="50" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'>
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </FormTemplate>
        </EditFormSettings>

    </MasterTableView>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.....................................
Code of my aspx page - in which i am loading the above usercontrol in Radwindow

On click of EDIT button - below code i have written-

```
RadWindow window = new RadWindow();
window.Height = Unit.Pixel(500);
window.Width = Unit.Pixel(500);
window.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;
UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("../../Controls/TypeUserControl.ascx");
uc.EnableViewState = false;
window.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
pnl.Controls.Add(window);
```

When I click on `Add New Record` in usercontrol it throws the exception "Failed to load view state:"

I have aspx page on which this user control is loaded is being inherited by my BasePage.

Exception is coming in OnPreRender of base page

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

User control - code behing

```
    public partial class TypeUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    protected void rgrd1Types_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           //dbase call
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SetValidationMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void rgrd1_InsertCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //dbase call

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SetValidationMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line is throwing the error..?what if you remove the path and just have the following 
`UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("TypeUserControl.ascx");`

Comment: exception is coming on PreRender event of Base page

Comment: please read the following answer located here.. looks like you may not need that call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984242/why-and-when-to-override-and-use-onprerender-in-asp-net

Comment: the problem is -the project is existing one - and i cannot change the BasePage...any other option pls

Comment: will you please provide the code behind for the User Control?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the issue, but your HTML is not correct in your Form Template

> ```
>                     <table>
>
>                             <td>
>                                 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtType" Width="50" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'>
>                                 </telerik:RadTextBox>
>
>                             </td>
>                         </tr>
>
>                     </table>
> ```

you are missing the opening `<tr>` tag.  this could have something to do with the issue.

you should double check all your code to make sure that it is correct.

--

I am also guessing that you should remove this line of code from the Edit button's `OnClick()` event

```
    uc.EnableViewState = false;
```

Comment: No- I have missed tr - but that shouldn't be the real root cause.

Comment: @NewCoder I have added something else to my answer as well

Comment: even after adding the code -its not working [same error]

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate the control on postback as you add it dynamically.
Recreate or Add the control in the Init_page Eventhandler, there you can check the type of event or control, that caused the postback, to know that you should recreate this control.
Can you post the code-behind file.

EDIT:
It's a long time ago, when I did this. But here is a working example.
I think there is a better way.
Check the keys collection, which button caused the postback, if it is a certain button in your ascx control then readd your control to the page or whereever you put it, but it must be the same place on postback, otherwise you will get an error, I think.

> protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)      {           base.OnInit(e);
>
> ```
>       if (this.Page.IsPostBack)           {
>           var x = base.DeterminePostBackMode();
>
>           if (x.Keys.Get(3).Contains("btnInControl"))
>           {
>               Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx");
>               this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
>           }       
> } 
> }
> ```

Comment: can you elaborate litte more on this - my understanding is when i click on Button [Edit] its a making a post back call - then how do i recreate the contorl on page_init

Comment: updated my answer... this is the basic implementation, you have to optimize it later.

Comment: When i click on "Add new record" button of USER CONTROL - i am getting P = null  [ var p = GetPostBackControl(this.Page)]

Answer (score 0):

It has been a year since you posted this issue but just in case someone still facing this: here is the main root of this type of error. I have been struggling big time with it.

- The easiest way to fix your bug is to set to the control you add dynamically :

  ```
  EnableViewState = false
  ```
- If you need the Viewstate, the other options you have are to add the control you add dynamically onInit, or recreate it on every Postback.

Hope it helps.

See [Funkylife's comment](http://forums.asp.net/t/1295517.aspx?Failed%20to%20load%20viewstate%20The%20control%20tree%20into%20which%20viewstate%20is%20being%20loaded%20must%20match%20the%20control%20tree%20that%20was%20used%20to%20save%20viewstate%20during%20the%20previous%20request%20For%20example%20when%20adding%20controls%20dynamically%20the%20controls%20added%20during%20a%20post%20back%20) for more information.